# Previous and Next inconsistency in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple thumbnail oriented slideshow functionality - when clicking on the thumbnail, it loads the image from data attribute.

I have now implemented a Previous and Next functionality to skip between those (always starting from the selected slide).

**Problem**: The sequence is unfortunately, not able to keep up and somehow not keeping the count of where it should be.

**Note:** Clicking on the thumbnails works just fine.

```js
$('#product-gallery-super').children().click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var prodImg = $(this).attr('data-image');
  var imgSrc = $(this).children().attr('src')

  if (imgSrc != '/images/imagecomingsoon_en.jpg') {

    $(this).addClass("active-thumbnail").siblings().removeClass("active-thumbnail");

    $('.main-image').attr('src', prodImg);

  }

});

$("#next").click(function() {
  if ($("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").next().length != 0) {
    $("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").next().addClass('active-thumbnail').prev().removeClass('active-thumbnail');

    imageManage($("#product-gallery-super a").last().data('image'));

  } else {
    $("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").removeClass('active-thumbnail');
    $("#product-gallery-super a").first().addClass('active-thumbnail');

    imageManage($("#product-gallery-super a").first().data('image'));

  }
  return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  if ($("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").prev().length != 0) {
    $("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").prev().addClass('active-thumbnail').next().removeClass('active-thumbnail');
    imageManage($("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").prev().data('image'));

  } else {
    $("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").removeClass('active-thumbnail');
    $("#product-gallery-super a").last().addClass('active-thumbnail');

    imageManage($("#product-gallery-super a").last().data('image'));
  }
  return false;
});

function imageManage(target) {
  return $('.main-image').attr('src', target);
}
```

```css
.active-thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="main-image image-resize" src="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=1" data-zoom-image="http://placehold.it/1000x2000?text=1" onerror="comingSoonMain(this)">
<button name="next" id="next">Next</button>
<button name="prev" id="prev">Prev</button>

<div id="product-gallery-super">
  <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery active-thumbnail" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=1">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=2">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=3">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=4">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=5">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=5">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="product-zoom-gallery" data-image="http://placehold.it/300x400?text=6">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=6">
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: You're not passing the correct image to `imageManage()` when you click the next and previous buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call should be:

```
imageManage($("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").data('image'));
```

Comment: and replace:  if ($("#product-gallery-super .active-thumbnail").next().next().length != 0) {